# Makefile conundrum

Tags: makefile

My makefile tries three different ways to call `FileExists`.

The second try, `Try2`, calls `eval`/`call`/`FileExist` inline. But for a file that does *not* exist, `Try2` always sets `CallInline` to `1` when it should be `0`. Why?

The third try, `Try3`, calls `eval`/`call`/`FileExist` and stores the result in a variable *then* checks that variable. This works fine for files that do and do not exist.

```
define FileExists
    $(and $(wildcard $(1)),1)
endef

define FileCheck

    #Try1
    $(eval Imm=$(call FileExists,$(1)))

    #Try2
    $(eval $(if $(call FileExists,$(1)),\
            $(eval CallInline:=1),\
            $(eval CallInline:=0)))

    #Try3
    $(eval ExistsVar=$(call FileExists,$(1)))
    $(eval $(if $(ExistsVar),\
            $(eval FromVar:=1),\
            $(eval FromVar:=0)))

    @echo $(1) Inline=[$(CallInline)]. Variable=[$(FromVar)].  Immeditate=[$(Imm)]
endef

FC:
    $(call FileCheck,./include/NotExist.h)
    $(call FileCheck,./include/DoesExist.h)
```

Here is the output:

```
#Try1
#Try2
#Try3
./include/NotExist.h Inline=[1]. Variable=[0]. Immeditate=[]
#Try1
#Try2
#Try3
./include/DoesExist.h Inline=[1]. Variable=[1]. Immeditate=[1]
```

This `./include/NotExist.h Inline=[1].` should be `0`.
Can anyone please shed some light on this?

Comment: You are assuming `make` as a fully scoped programming language, but it just isn't. I don't know the exact rules for `eval` inside of an `eval`, but even ignoring this, I wouldn't bet on correct execution of your makefile under parallelism - AFAIK variables reside in a global space, which makes your function subject to race conditions. I would not go beyond the direct use of `wildcard` also as a boolean predicate. If the file isn't there, it gives the empty string ie. "false", else the filename which is "true" as far as `make` is concerned.

Comment: Remove the leading spaces on front of `$(and $(wildcard $(1)),1)`. Note: your Makefile is uselessly complicated. Try maybe `$(eval CallInline:=$(if $(call FileExists,$(1)),1,0))` to avoid nested evals. Same for `FromVar`.

Comment: But as using `eval` in recipes is almost always wrong you should probably rework all this.

Comment: How would you rework it?

Im only asking how/why the two ways (Try2 and Try3) give different results,  not on structure.

The results are consistent. If there were race conditions Id expect to see inconsistent results.

Comment: @AndrewAUS There is no race condition. As I explained in my first comment the different behavior you observe with `Try2` is due to the leading spaces in the definition of your `FileExists` function. Because of them your `if` always evaluates as true. And in order to rework all this in a more make-ish style we would need to know a bit more about what you try to achieve. Why do you try to define make variables in a recipe? Why don't you define them "normally"?

Comment: @AndrewAUS From the [GNU make documentation of the `if` conditional](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-if-1): _The first argument, condition, first has all preceding and trailing whitespace stripped, then is expanded. If it expands to any non-empty string, then the condition is considered to be true. If it expands to an empty string, the condition is considered to be false._ A string of spaces or a tab is not an empty string.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Thanks! the leading spaces in `FileExsits` was causing the different behaviour.  But I cant see why (for my own sanity) `Try3` passed, while `Try2` failed?

Where does, after the expansion, the `Try2` get a non-empty string? (compared to `Try3`).

Is there way to get `make` to show me what expansions it does?

Comment: In `Try3` you assign the expansion of `$(call FileExists,$(1))` to variable `ExistsVar`. As for any variable assignment the leading spaces of the right hand side are stripped off. And yes, you can ask make to show you the result of expansions. Try `$(info |$(call FileExists,$(1))|)`.